# Interactive YouTube video navigation

Tags: youtube, webvideos

I want to create a youtube video based on the technique used in this video: [Interactive Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m97O1dQAyhc). How can I make annotation(spotlight) on youtube that will link to a video and start at various times.  (Like the buttons on the bottom of the video.)

Example:

If I click the spotlight 5 sec, then step the slider to 15 sec.

If I click the spotlight 6 sec, then step the slider to 16 sec.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I have reopened your question and attempted to further clarify what it appears you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make a separate spotlight for each different link.  So one spotlight goes from 5 seconds to 6 seconds, and another spotlight goes from 6 seconds to 7 seconds.  Each of them starts your linked video at a different point (15 seconds, 16 seconds, or whatever).

It's easy to set the starting time within an annotation link.  When you create the annotation, and add the link URL, it will ask you about the starting point.  (The default is 0.00, the beginning of the video.) You just set it there before you publish your annotations.

Note that annotations don't yet work on mobile devices (as far as I know).

[Here's a useful page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/92710?hl=en) that instructs you how to create and use annotations, in case you need some more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also think this solution, but I was hoping exist an easier one.

Comment: I've been making YouTube videos since 2006. I WISH there was an easier way, but I haven't found it yet!